# Mounting Encrypted Softraid on OpenBSD

Tags: mount, openbsd, init-script

**The Setup**

I have a machine that is running OpenBSD, it has two SSDs in it: `sd0` and `sd1`.

I've setup each SSD with two partitions `a` and `d`.

From there I've built two mirrors using `bioctl`:

The first mirror is built from `sd0a` and `sd1a` ; this shows up as `sd2`

The second mirror is built from `sd0d` and `sd1d` ; this shows up as `sd3`

The root of the system `/` is mounted to `sd2a`.

I then used `bioctl` to build an encrypted softraid on-top of `sd3` ; this shows up as `sd4`.

The rest of the system is mounted on `sd4` : `/usr`, `/home`, `/tmp`, `/var` etc..

**The Issue**

When the system boots it obviously complains it can't find `/var` `/usr` `/tmp` etc. I am able to drop to a shell and manually attach the encrypted container with the command: `bioctl -c C -l /dev/sd3a softraid0`. Then I exit the shell and system boots fine. But when I try to automate this with a script in `rc.local` or `rc.securelevel` it doesn't work...

Here's the script I've tried in `rc.local` and `rc.securelevel`

```
bioctl sd4 > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
echo "Mounting..."
bioctl -c C -l /dev/sd3a softraid0
fi
```

Thank you for taking the time to look at this!

**edit**
As asked for here is the boot message - I've marked the spot it gets to when it breaks and complains it can't find /var /tmp /usr etc.

```
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: avail mem = 33187635200 (31650MB)
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: mpath0 at root
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: scsibus0 at mpath0: 256 targets
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: mainbus0 at root
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: bios0 at mainbus0: SMBIOS rev. 3.0 @ 0xea820 (69 entries)
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: bios0: vendor American Megatrends Inc. version "1.70" date 12/18/2017
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: bios0: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7B09
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: acpi0 at bios0: rev 2
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: acpi0: sleep states S0 S3 S4 S5
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: acpi0: tables DSDT FACP APIC FPDT FIDT SSDT SSDT SSDT MCFG SSDT CRAT CDIT HPET SSDT UEFI SSDT SSDT
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: acpi0: wakeup devices D0A1(S4) D0A2(S4) D0A3(S4) D0A4(S4) D0A5(S4) D0A6(S4) D0A7(S4) D0B0(S4) D0B1(S4) D0B2(S4) D0B3(S4) D0B4(S4) D0B5(S4) D0B6(S4) D0B7(S4) D0C0(S4) [...]
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: acpitimer0 at acpi0: 3579545 Hz, 32 bits
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: acpimadt0 at acpi0 addr 0xfee00000: PC-AT compat
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu0 at mainbus0: apid 0 (boot processor)
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu0: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1900X 8-Core Processor, 3800.79 MHz
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu0: FPU,VME,DE,PSE,TSC,MSR,PAE,MCE,CX8,APIC,SEP,MTRR,PGE,MCA,CMOV,PAT,PSE36,CFLUSH,MMX,FXSR,SSE,SSE2,HTT,SSE3,PCLMUL,MWAIT,SSSE3,FMA3,CX16,SSE4.1,SSE4.2,MOVBE,POPCNT,AES,XSAVE,AVX,F16C,RDRAND,NXE,MMXX,FFXSR,PAGE1GB,RDTSCP,LONG,LAHF,CMPLEG,SVM,EAPICSP,AMCR8,ABM,SSE4A,MASSE,3DNOWP,OSVW,SKINIT,TOPEXT,ITSC,FSGSBASE,BMI1,AVX2,SMEP,BMI2,RDSEED,ADX,SMAP,CLFLUSHOPT,SHA
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu0: 64KB 64b/line 4-way I-cache, 32KB 64b/line 8-way D-cache, 512KB 64b/line 8-way L2 cache, 16MB 64b/line 32-way L3 cache
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu0: ITLB 64 4KB entries fully associative, 64 4MB entries fully associative
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu0: DTLB 64 4KB entries fully associative, 64 4MB entries fully associative
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu0: TSC frequency 3800785080 Hz
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu0: smt 0, core 0, package 0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: mtrr: Pentium Pro MTRR support, 8 var ranges, 88 fixed ranges
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu0: apic clock running at 100MHz
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu0: mwait min=64, max=64, IBE
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu1 at mainbus0: apid 2 (application processor)
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu1: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1900X 8-Core Processor, 3800.01 MHz
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu1: FPU,VME,DE,PSE,TSC,MSR,PAE,MCE,CX8,APIC,SEP,MTRR,PGE,MCA,CMOV,PAT,PSE36,CFLUSH,MMX,FXSR,SSE,SSE2,HTT,SSE3,PCLMUL,MWAIT,SSSE3,FMA3,CX16,SSE4.1,SSE4.2,MOVBE,POPCNT,AES,XSAVE,AVX,F16C,RDRAND,NXE,MMXX,FFXSR,PAGE1GB,RDTSCP,LONG,LAHF,CMPLEG,SVM,EAPICSP,AMCR8,ABM,SSE4A,MASSE,3DNOWP,OSVW,SKINIT,TOPEXT,ITSC,FSGSBASE,BMI1,AVX2,SMEP,BMI2,RDSEED,ADX,SMAP,CLFLUSHOPT,SHA
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu1: 64KB 64b/line 4-way I-cache, 32KB 64b/line 8-way D-cache, 512KB 64b/line 8-way L2 cache, 16MB 64b/line 32-way L3 cache
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu1: ITLB 64 4KB entries fully associative, 64 4MB entries fully associative
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu1: DTLB 64 4KB entries fully associative, 64 4MB entries fully associative
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu1: smt 0, core 2, package 0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu15 at mainbus0: apid 23 (application processor)
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu15: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1900X 8-Core Processor, 3800.01 MHz
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu15: FPU,VME,DE,PSE,TSC,MSR,PAE,MCE,CX8,APIC,SEP,MTRR,PGE,MCA,CMOV,PAT,PSE36,CFLUSH,MMX,FXSR,SSE,SSE2,HTT,SSE3,PCLMUL,MWAIT,SSSE3,FMA3,CX16,SSE4.1,SSE4.2,MOVBE,POPCNT,AES,XSAVE,AVX,F16C,RDRAND,NXE,MMXX,FFXSR,PAGE1GB,RDTSCP,LONG,LAHF,CMPLEG,SVM,EAPICSP,AMCR8,ABM,SSE4A,MASSE,3DNOWP,OSVW,SKINIT,TOPEXT,ITSC,FSGSBASE,BMI1,AVX2,SMEP,BMI2,RDSEED,ADX,SMAP,CLFLUSHOPT,SHA
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu15: 64KB 64b/line 4-way I-cache, 32KB 64b/line 8-way D-cache, 512KB 64b/line 8-way L2 cache, 16MB 64b/line 32-way L3 cache
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu15: ITLB 64 4KB entries fully associative, 64 4MB entries fully associative
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu15: DTLB 64 4KB entries fully associative, 64 4MB entries fully associative
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu15: smt 0, core 23, package 0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: "PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: acpibtn0 at acpi0: PWRB
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: "AMDI0030" at acpi0 not configured
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: "AMDI0010" at acpi0 not configured
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: "PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: "AMDIF030" at acpi0 not configured
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: "PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: cpu0: 3800 MHz: speeds: 3800 3000 2200 MHz
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pci0 at mainbus0 bus 0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pci1 at ppb0 bus 1
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: xhci0 at pci1 dev 0 function 0 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x43ba rev 0x02: msi
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: usb0 at xhci0: USB revision 3.0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: uhub0 at usb0 configuration 1 interface 0 "AMD xHCI root hub" rev 3.00/1.00 addr 1
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: ahci0 at pci1 dev 0 function 1 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x43b6 rev 0x02: msi, AHCI 1.3.1
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: scsibus1 at ahci0: 32 targets
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: xhci1 at pci3 dev 0 function 0 vendor "ASMedia", unknown product 0x2142 rev 0x00: msi
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: usb1 at xhci1: USB revision 3.0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: uhub1 at usb1 configuration 1 interface 0 "ASMedia xHCI root hub" rev 3.00/1.00 addr 1
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: ppb3 at pci2 dev 2 function 0 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x43b4 rev 0x02: msi
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: em0 at pci8 dev 0 function 0 "Intel I211" rev 0x03: msi, address 30:9c:23:64:e8:f3
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: ppb8 at pci2 dev 7 function 0 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x43b4 rev 0x02: msi
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pci9 at ppb8 bus 9
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: ppb9 at pci0 dev 1 function 2 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1453 rev 0x00: msi
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pci10 at ppb9 bus 10
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: nvme0 at pci10 dev 0 function 0 "Samsung SM961/PM961 NVMe" rev 0x00: msi, NVMe 1.2
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: nvme0: Samsung SSD 960 EVO 250GB, firmware 3B7QCXE7, serial S3ESNX0JB78420A
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: scsibus2 at nvme0: 1 targets
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: sd0 at scsibus2 targ 0 lun 0: <NVMe, Samsung SSD 960, 3B7Q> SCSI4 0/direct fixed
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: sd0: 238475MB, 512 bytes/sector, 488397168 sectors
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pci11 at ppb10 bus 11
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x145a (class instrumentation unknown subclass 0x00, rev 0x00) at pci11 dev 0 function 0 not configured
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1456 (class crypto subclass miscellaneous, rev 0x00) at pci11 dev 0 function 2 not configured
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: xhci2 at pci11 dev 0 function 3 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x145c rev 0x00: msi
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: usb2 at xhci2: USB revision 3.0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: uhub2 at usb2 configuration 1 interface 0 "AMD xHCI root hub" rev 3.00/1.00 addr 1
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pchb6 at pci0 dev 8 function 0 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1452 rev 0x00
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: ppb11 at pci0 dev 8 function 1 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1454 rev 0x00
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pci12 at ppb11 bus 12
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1455 (class instrumentation unknown subclass 0x00, rev 0x00) at pci12 dev 0 function 0 not configured
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: ahci1 at pci12 dev 0 function 2 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x7901 rev 0x51: msi, AHCI 1.3.1
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: scsibus3 at ahci1: 32 targets
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: azalia0 at pci12 dev 0 function 3 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1457 rev 0x00: msi
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: azalia0: codecs: Realtek/0x1220
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: audio0 at azalia0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x790b (class serial bus subclass SMBus, rev 0x59) at pci0 dev 20 function 0 not configured
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: isa0 at pcib0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: isadma0 at isa0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: com0 at isa0 port 0x3f8/8 irq 4: ns16550a, 16 byte fifo
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pckbc0 at isa0 port 0x60/5 irq 1 irq 12
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pckbd0 at pckbc0 (kbd slot)
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: wskbd0 at pckbd0: console keyboard
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: vga0 at isa0 port 0x3b0/48 iomem 0xa0000/131072
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: wsdisplay0 at vga0 mux 1: console (80x25, vt100 emulation), using wskbd0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: wsdisplay0: screen 1-5 added (80x25, vt100 emulation)
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pcppi0 at isa0 port 0x61
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: spkr0 at pcppi0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pci13 at mainbus0 bus 64
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pci14 at ppb12 bus 65
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: nvme1 at pci14 dev 0 function 0 "Samsung SM951/PM951 NVMe" rev 0x01: msi, NVMe 1.1
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: nvme1: Samsung SSD 950 PRO 512GB, firmware 1B0QBXX7, serial S2GMNX0H921434T
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: scsibus4 at nvme1: 1 targets
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: sd1 at scsibus4 targ 0 lun 0: <NVMe, Samsung SSD 950, 1B0Q> SCSI4 0/direct fixed
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: sd1: 488386MB, 512 bytes/sector, 1000215216 sectors
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pchb25 at pci13 dev 2 function 0 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1452 rev 0x00
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pchb26 at pci13 dev 3 function 0 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1452 rev 0x00
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: ppb13 at pci13 dev 3 function 1 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1453 rev 0x00: msi
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pci15 at ppb13 bus 66
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: vendor "ATI", unknown product 0x67df (class display subclass VGA, rev 0xe7) at pci15 dev 0 function 0 not configured
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: azalia1 at pci15 dev 0 function 1 vendor "ATI", unknown product 0xaaf0 rev 0x00: msi
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: azalia1: no supported codecs
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pchb27 at pci13 dev 4 function 0 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1452 rev 0x00
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pchb28 at pci13 dev 7 function 0 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1452 rev 0x00
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: ppb14 at pci13 dev 7 function 1 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1454 rev 0x00
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pci16 at ppb14 bus 67
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x145a (class instrumentation unknown subclass 0x00, rev 0x00) at pci16 dev 0 function 0 not configured
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1456 (class crypto subclass miscellaneous, rev 0x00) at pci16 dev 0 function 2 not configured
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: xhci3 at pci16 dev 0 function 3 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x145c rev 0x00: msi
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: usb3 at xhci3: USB revision 3.0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: uhub3 at usb3 configuration 1 interface 0 "AMD xHCI root hub" rev 3.00/1.00 addr 1
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pchb29 at pci13 dev 8 function 0 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1452 rev 0x00
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: ppb15 at pci13 dev 8 function 1 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1454 rev 0x00
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: pci17 at ppb15 bus 68
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x1455 (class instrumentation unknown subclass 0x00, rev 0x00) at pci17 dev 0 function 0 not configured
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: ahci2 at pci17 dev 0 function 2 vendor "AMD", unknown product 0x7901 rev 0x51: msi, AHCI 1.3.1
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: scsibus5 at ahci2: 32 targets
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: uhidev0 at uhub0 port 21 configuration 1 interface 0 "Microsoft Microsoft\M-. Digital Media oard 3000" rev 2.00/2.00 addr 2
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: uhidev0: iclass 3/1
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: ukbd0 at uhidev0: 8 variable keys, 6 key codes
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: wskbd1 at ukbd0 mux 1
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: wskbd1: connecting to wsdisplay0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: uhidev1 at uhub0 port 21 configuration 1 interface 1 "Microsoft Microsoft\M-. Digital Media oard 3000" rev 2.00/2.00 addr 2
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: uhidev1: iclass 3/0, 3 report ids
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: uhid0 at uhidev1 reportid 1: input=7, output=0, feature=0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: uhid1 at uhidev1 reportid 3: input=1, output=0, feature=0
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: vscsi0 at root
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: scsibus6 at vscsi0: 256 targets
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: softraid0 at root
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: scsibus7 at softraid0: 256 targets
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: sd2 at scsibus7 targ 1 lun 0: <OPENBSD, SR RAID 1, 006> SCSI2 0/direct fixed
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: sd2: 20479MB, 512 bytes/sector, 41942512 sectors
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: sd3 at scsibus7 targ 2 lun 0: <OPENBSD, SR RAID 1, 006> SCSI2 0/direct fixed
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: sd3: 217992MB, 512 bytes/sector, 446448433 sectors
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: root on sd2a (1ff7dd9b647c5f6f.a) swap on sd2b dump on sd2b
*** This is where I have to drop to a shell and manually attach the encrypted softraid0 ***
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: sd4 at scsibus7 targ 3 lun 0: <OPENBSD, SR CRYPTO, 006> SCSI2 0/direct fixed
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql /bsd: sd4: 217992MB, 512 bytes/sector, 446447905 sectors
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql sendsyslog: dropped 1 message, error 57
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql ntpd[66920]: /var/db/ntpd.drift is empty
Mar 12 06:52:10 sql savecore: /dev/sd2b: Device not configured
Mar 12 06:52:15 sql reorder_kernel: kernel relinking done
```

Also after I manually mount the encrypted softraid and the boot finishes everything works, here is the output from mount:

```
/dev/sd2a on / type ffs (local)
/dev/sd4k on /home type ffs (local, nodev, nosuid)
/dev/sd4d on /tmp type ffs (local, nodev, nosuid)
/dev/sd4f on /usr type ffs (local, nodev)
/dev/sd4g on /usr/X11R6 type ffs (local, nodev)
/dev/sd4h on /usr/local type ffs (local, nodev, wxallowed)
/dev/sd4j on /usr/obj type ffs (local, nodev, nosuid)
/dev/sd4i on /usr/src type ffs (local, nodev, nosuid)
/dev/sd4e on /var type ffs (local, nodev, nosuid)
```

Comment: Two down votes but zero feedback - if there's an issue with the question please let me know.

Comment: did you use `installboot(8)` to install `boot(8)` in the boot storage area of the softraid volume?

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  When I ran the installer I selected sd2a as / then in the next step of the installer I initialized sd4 and created the remaining partitions(/var /usr /tmp etc). What I don't understand is why the script in rc.local isn't running....should I be putting it in rc somewhere?

Comment: Can you share the boot process? As it should say:

Comment: rc.local is probably to late in the boot process for your script. But normally you don't want to change the default `rc` scripts.  The softraid  should show up as an `sr` disk. And your boot prompt should look like: `boot> boot sr0a:/bsd`

Comment: who downvotes a question? It's a perfectly valid question unless otherwise explain why, here have my vote, I find your question interesting and want to know the answer.

Comment: What's the rationale behind encrypting `/usr/*`? Except _maybe_ for stuff you install under `/usr/local` and that for some reason you want to keep secret in case someone steals your disks, all the rest is publicly available anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a bit of digging and reading here's what I've found:
rc.local and even rc.securelevel are called far too late in the rc scripts to be used to mount the rest of the file system. A quick grep through the rc scripts made it clear the encrypted softraid needs to be attached just before the "Check filesystems" code runs in rc. To make sure the code only runs on startup I've added the following just above the "Check filesystems" script in rc:

```
# ADDED - This mounts the encrypted filesystem
bioctl sd4 > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
echo "Time to decrypt and mount the rest of your filesystem..."
bioctl -c C -l /dev/sd3a softraid0
fi
```

To be clear I don't like this solution as I will have to be wary with updates that replace/modify rc but I don't see a way around this. If someone from OpenBSD has a better solution please do let me know!

I know this is super basic but I figure this might save someone some time so I leave the question up. Also testing recovery/consistency of encrypted content sitting on top of a mirror that has lost a disk(and has been rebuilt) seems to fail. It doesn't seem to be able to see/handle the encrypted device - it's too bad OpenBSD can't quite yet handle this. You'll have to look at hardware solutions for the mirror and then use FDE in OpenBSD, or use a different O/S.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe your hack is a reasonable solution. I run `bioctl`/`fsck`/`mount` from `rc.securelevel` to mount the home dir on my laptop, but this won't work if you need it earlier in the boot process.

Answer (score -1):

As [explicitly stated in the FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq14.html#softraidFDE) : **"stacking" softraid modes (mirrored drives and encryption, for example) is not supported at this time**.

Comment: I'm aware of this - the question is why my script isn't running.

Comment: You're aware of this, so why are you doing it ? (encryption on sd3)